# In MySql how do I query a table to see if one column has two similar entries of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table called `CAT`

`CAT` has two columns `ID` and `NAME`

I forgot to add a unique constraint for these two columns.. and in my database I want to make sure I don't have any wrong entries before I add that constraint.

So I want a query to make sure every `ID` has unique values in the `NAME` column. How can I query for this?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM cat GROUP By name HAVING cnt > 1`

Comment: @Alex this is the solution described in the answers to the duplicate questions...